Xubuntu 23.10 install CD taking too long to boot
I am trying to install Xubuntu 23.10 on my iMac (27-inch, Mid 2011) to replace Ubuntu 22.04. I booted the disc using the "EFI Boot" option, but at the Xubuntu loading screen, the installation takes a long time to load. Is this normal or is it a hardware or software problem?

Considering the facts that your computer is more than 10 years old and your Ubuntu installation media is most likely a USB 2 thumb drive, then your long wait at the Xubuntu 23.10 loading screen is most likely normal and not a hardware or software problem. This has given you the serendipitous opportunity to install the latest LTS version of Ubuntu 24.04 which has 10 years of support for personal use on up to 5 machines if the free Ubuntu Pro option is enabled.
Ubuntu 24.04 is scheduled to be released sometime today. Canonical has announced 12 years of LTS support for Ubuntu 24.04, but since it hasn't been released yet the details of how this extended period of LTS support works have not been released yet either.
